# Magento 2 resized images visually corrupted

Tags: debugging, magento2, gd, image-resizing, corruption

In our magento 2.4.6 website some images are resized viually corrupted.
There are some ascii characters replacing some pixel blocks.
The source image is correct, no error message , not visually corrupted.
I run `convert public_html/pub/media/catalog/product/p/o/powx308_1.jpg -quality 80 public_html/pub/test.jpg` and the resulting image is visually correct.
I deleted the image from the cache to force creating of a new image, the resulting image is visually corrupted.
Example: https://i.imgur.com/XyYWrnA.png
Anyone else experiencing this?

Expected: Magento should resize image and the resulting image should be visually correct representation of the original
Result: Some images are generated (and regenerated) visually incorrect.
Example: https://i.imgur.com/XyYWrnA.png

Comment: Did you try imagick? I always have bad experiences using gd. you will need to to install it on the server then change the configuration to use it: dev/image/default_adapter